# How to prevent page crashes in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, plugins, javascript

I use the most recent Chrome version on Windows 7. Since I discovered tabbed browsing, I couldn't help preventing myself from opening too many tabs simultaneously.

With Google chrome, I frequently get pages crashed and others sometimes responding very slowly.

Is there a solution for that? What is the most probable cause for page crashing, that can be disabled and get red of this nuisance, e.g. Javascripts, Flash, etc.

Comment: I get a bug where javascript stops executing on *some* domains. but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Most problems are from javascript. You can disable your javascript, but you shouldn't do it. In any case, when Chrome tab crashes, it doesn't break other tabs so I think this doesn't matter. Flash and browser plugins are also possible source of your problems

Comment: Thanks genesis. It seems indeed that Java script is a big part of the problem if not the whole problem. I don't know yet how many of my extensions will live without Java scripts. I had to turn it on again on this domain to write this comment. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Flash, or any plugin for that matter will cause tabs to crash.

Comment: I discovered that one of my favorite extensions, diigo, needs javascripts. So I will need to turn it on on every site I need it! By the way, it often happens when a tab crashes, many other tabs in the same window crash too!

Answer (score 1):

There's a known bug where hitting the [Enter key results in lot of tabs crashing](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96692). You might be a victim of that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Mine crashed at damn near every website i liked. (Youtube, Google, yea google in google chrome, craigslist etc) but it was a Privacy Safeguard extension that did it for me. It was installed by google chrome in the last update and throwing up false crashes constantly. Just uninstall it through control panel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are from bookmark folders, I would recommend splitting your pages into multiple sub-folders as I have had to do previously. Every new tab in chrome makes a new process (sometimes known as a fork) for each tab, when you open them all simultaneously your computer is bombarded with multiple processes at the same time. If you opened them up in groups, chrome  should be more compliant.